# Recover a username/password

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm trying to add the ability for users to recover their username and/or password to phpacademy's OOP login/register tutorials. I've started but I don't know how to continue. The code I have is based on phpacademy's old non-oop login/register tutorials.

Here's the code:
recover.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
$user = new User();
if ($user->isLoggedIn()) {
    Redirect::to('index.php');
}

if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
?>
    <p>We've emailed you</p>
<?php
} else {

    $mode_allowed = array('username', 'password');

    if (isset($_GET['mode']) === true && in_array($_GET['mode'], $mode_allowed) === true) {
        if (isset($_POST['email']) === true && empty($_POST['email']) === false) {
            $email = Input::get('email');
            if ($user->emailExists($email) === true) {
                $user->recover($_GET['mode'], $email);
                Redirect::to('recover.php?success');
            } else {
                //Your custom error saying that that email does not exist
                echo 'That email does not exist'; 
            }
        }
    ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Please enter your email address:<br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
                </li>
                <li><input type="submit" class="sub-btn tx-shadow" value="Recover"></li>
            </ul>
        </form>

    <?php
    } else {
        Redirect::to('index.php');
    }
}
```

The classes I have in User.php:

```
public function emailExists($email){
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM `users`
            WHERE `email` = ?
    ";
    $result = $this->_db->query($sql, array($email));
    //return $result->count() === 1;

    // Above is the same as this:
    //return ($result->count() === 1) ? true : false;

    // Or this:
    if($result->count() === 0){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
public function recover($mode, $email) {

    //Get data of user
    $user_data = $this->getUserByEmail($email);
    // Email User

    if ($mode == 'username') {
        $this->sendActivation($email, 'Your Username', 'Hello'.$user_data['first_name']. '\n\nYour username is: '.$user_data['username'].'\n\nThank you\nBusarna');
    } else if ($mode == 'password') {
        $generated_password = substr(sha1(rand(999, 999999)), 0, 10);
        //update password
    }
}

public function getUserByEmail($email) {
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM `users`
            WHERE `email` = ?
            "

    $result = $this->_db->query($sql, array($email));
    //return $result;
}
```

The emailExists function work. The problems I have is that I don't know how to get all the info from a user using their email and store the info to use them like this:

```
$this->sendActivation($email, 'Your Username', 'Hello'.$user_data['first_name']. '\n\nYour username is: '.$user_data['username'].'\n\nThank you\nBusarna');
```

I have a class above for it but I don't know how to change it to get it working (getUserByEmail). Also, I don't know if the way above is a good way to generate a password (unhashed, it will be hashed when put in the db), I don't know how to update the password and force the users to change it on the next login.

Right now I get this error if I go to recover.php: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE) in D:\Program\xampp\htdocs\website\classes\User.php on line 225** This is that line:

```
$result = $this->_db->query($sql, array($email));
```

If you guys need anything else just let me know.

DB.php class:

```
public static function getInstance() {
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
        self::$_instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if ($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

var_dump($user_data);

object(DB)#3 (5) { ["_pdo":"DB":private]=> object(PDO)#4 (0) { } ["_query":"DB":private]=> object(PDOStatement)#7 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(55) "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ? " } ["_error":"DB":private]=> bool(false) ["_results":"DB":private]=> object(stdClass)#5 (18) { ["id"]=> string(2) "28" ["username"]=> string(8) "Busarna4" ["password"]=> string(128) "3759d763d01ee1259d8f4a74914335be4e3e06622d8ffc455789cbd8c46b5800d1892794cde2de1b0f6a1cf8e1effc642877b7937b7c0deaf9036e558474eb5c" ["salt"]=> string(100) "Àw¶10$ê!º   L-Kó„Ö §òŸÔK*{áëRÌÕÆé³X ï« Âá*Ú ™ü²ÅK§þ3 hõHï¬Å+c¦kºá`³Trë_ßÙáû,ð¡_Ë‹Žz0" ["email"]=> string(20) "busarna4@hotmail.com" ["email_code"]=> string(32) "ae3e9ad790297c627a656157d5306d1e" ["k1"]=> string(64) "42a86fe29289c83a8d91a990e49b62c3866192c983e51070df0c63697020b5ce" ["k2"]=> string(64) "d7827e522bbbdadfd14afd2edbae18d5a6f3c39a490154c178b2eec240d7b576" ["k3"]=> string(64) "8051c951f1ec043d5297765adddd760e1f8506d1785dfdb55dabe564b6326b86" ["first_name"]=> string(0) "" ["last_name"]=> string(0) "" ["gender"]=> string(4) "Male" ["profile"]=> string(0) "" ["avatar"]=> string(30) "images/default-Male-Avatar.png" ["lastlogin"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["joined"]=> string(19) "2014-06-22 21:22:36" ["group"]=> string(1) "1" ["activated"]=> string(1) "1" } ["_count":"DB":private]=> int(1) }

Does anyone know how to do this? All help appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Busarna

Comment: Uncomment `//return $result` in your getUserByEmail() function.

Comment: I noticed that I get an error because of that class. I added the error to the question. And uncommenting that doesn't do anything becasue of this error @Gudgip

Comment: put a `;` on the end of line 224.

Comment: I've done that, it was a typo. Can you read my comment underneath DanFromGermany's answer to see my next problem? @Gudgip

Comment: @Busarna4 next problem, next question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

In your function `query()` you used `fetchAll` that will return an two dimensional array even if you get a single record.

**Solution:**

1. Use `fetch()` instead for single record.

change the function:

```
public function query_single($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if ($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC:);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this->_results;
}
```

then change the other function to

```
public function getUserByEmail($email) {
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM `users`
            WHERE `email` = ?
            ";

    $result = $this->_db->query_single($sql, array($email));

    return $result;
}
```

finally

```
$this->sendActivation($email, 
                      'Your Username', 
                      'Hello'.$user_data['username'] 
                      .'\n\nYour username is: '.$user_data['username']
                      .'\n\nThank you\nBusarna');
```

Comment: I did that but I get this: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DB as array in D:\Program\xampp\htdocs\website\classes\User.php on line 212. This is that line: $this->sendActivation($email, 'Your Username', 'Hello'.$user_data[0]['first_name']. '\n\nYour username is: '.$user_data[0]['username'].'\n\nThank you\nBusarna'); @meda

Comment: Please show var_dump($user_data); we will get this sorted out

Comment: I added it to the question since it was too long for a comment @meda

Comment: @Busarna4 I see now  the function should return `$this->_results` not `$this` but you still have issue because `["first_name"]=> string(0) ""` is empty

Comment: Ohh, I forgot, that user haven't entered a first name. I think it works except for that I get this: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DB as array in D:\Program\xampp\htdocs\website\classes\User.php on line 213 which is this line: $this->sendActivation($email, 'Your Username', 'Hello'.$user_data[0]['username']. '\n\nYour username is: '.$user_data[0]['username'].'\n\nThank you\nBusarna');. I changed first_name to username but why do I get this error? @meda

Comment: because user data is not the result set it is an instance of the class, return `$this->_results` in the query() function @Busarna4

Comment: I did that but now I get this: Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::count() in D:\Program\xampp\htdocs\website\classes\User.php on line 182. This is that line: if($result->count() === 0){ in the emailExists function @meda

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57586/discussion-between-meda-and-busarna4).

Answer (score 3):

```
public function getUserByEmail($email) {
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM `users`
            WHERE `email` = ?
            ";
    //       ^-------------------------  missing semicolon

    $result = $this->_db->query($sql, array($email));

    // Don't forget to return the result:
    return $result;
}
```

`unexpected '$result'` means, it sees $result but it does expect something in the line before $result. The *command* before the line with $result is not finished.

Comment: I added that now. It was a typo. How do I save everything so I can do something like $user_data['first_name'] to get the first name into an email? @DanFromGermany

Comment: You fetch it from where it is stored and concat it with the strings in the mail function, just like you did.

Comment: @Gudgip hehe I saw your comment, travelled back in time by 3 minutes and then quickly wrote the answer ;-)

Comment: Right now I get this if I press recover with a valid email: 
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DB as array in D:\Program\xampp\htdocs\website\classes\User.php on line 212 @DanFromGermany

Comment: This is that line: $this->sendActivation($email, 'Your Username', 'Hello'.$user_data['first_name']. '\n\nYour username is: '.$user_data['username'].'\n\nThank you\nBusarna'); @DanFromGermany

Comment: @Busarna4 the problem is here maybe `$result = $this->_db->query($sql, array($email));` you return the query, but you need to `fetch` the results or `execute` the query before beeing able to access the results. We need to know the `db` class to verify and investigate.

Comment: @Busarna4 have you checked if `$this->_error` is set true maybe?